# How to get the value of base class c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to print a table like below:

```
1 Data types and expressions
  1.1 Data types in C++
  1.2 Constants
      1.2.1 What are Constants
      1.2.2 Mathematical constant
      1.2.3 Literal constant
  1.3 Variables
      1.3.1 What are variables
      1.3.2 Variable naming rules
  1.4 Operators in C++
  1.5 Arithmetic operators
      1.5.1 Basic rithmetic operators
```

Using class inheritance. This is my code up to now:

```
class First_Title {
public:
    string f_name;
    int f_num;
    First_Title(string fname, int fnum)
    {
        f_name = fname;
        f_num = fnum;
    };
    virtual void print()
    {
        cout<<f_num<<" "<<f_name<<endl;
    }

};

class Second_Title : public First_Title {
public:
    string s_name;
    int s_num;
    Second_Title(string f_name, int f_num, string s_name, int s_num) : First_Title(f_name, f_num), s_name(s_name), s_num(s_num)
    {};
    virtual void print()
    {
        cout<<setw(3)<<f_num<<"."<<s_num<<" "<<s_name<<endl;
    }
};

class Third_Title : public Second_Title {
public:
    string t_name;
    int t_num;
    Third_Title(string f_name, int f_num, string s_name, int s_num, string t_name, int t_num) : Second_Title(f_name, f_num, s_name, s_num), t_name(t_name), t_num(t_num)
    {};
    virtual void print()
    {
        cout<<setw(7)<<f_num<<"."<<s_num<<"."<<t_num<<" "<<t_name<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Third_Title book1("Data types and expressions", 1, "Constants", 2, "What are Constants", 1);
    Third_Title book2("Data types and expressions", 1, "Constants", 2, "Mathematical Constants", 2);
    Third_Title book3("Data types and expressions", 1, "Constants", 2, "Literal Constants", 3);
    book1.First_Title::print();
    book1.Second_Title::print();
    book1.print();
    book2.print();
    book3.print();
    return 0;
}
```

I think my code is inefficient, because the three instances book1, book2 and book3 has the same value for  f_name, f_num, s_name and s_num.

So what I thought is,
first, create an instance of First_Title, for example,

```
First_Title book1("Data types and expressions", 1)
```

And then create 5 instances of Second_Title, that inherits the values of book1, and then again create instances of Third_Title, that inherits the values of its base classes.

Is it possible to code like this?

Comment: Do you mean, you *don't* want to have these as base classes, but instead want just a single `Title` class, and then make a dynamic tree data structure out of it? In that case start by removing the inheritance.

Comment: If you are thinking about optimizing memory, you need to remove inheritance and design your application with some data structures, ex: Tree

Comment: This is not an appropriate use of class inheritance. Subclasses are for IS-A relationship between types, not for containers.

Comment: Each title has the same node type as the title itself. This means that `title` has parent-children relationship. Each node has the same properties. So, using this point, you can implement using `Tree` and `TreeNode`. Reference code for tree code is: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/135432/c-tree-class-implementation. If you are Korean, you can get a help from  https://blog.naver.com/PostView.nhn?blogId=justkukaro&logNo=220548164184

Answer (score 0):

So, ultimately you ask if its possible to code like this. The answer is yes, to some extent. However it is not really suggested since classes and inheritance is not supposed to be used in this way. If you're looking to create something like an index page from a book, you should try using trees like @MayurK suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general solution. It is a bit straightforward, but gives the general idea of a tree structure.

Struct Node represents a tree.

Function print is recursive. It is not usually a great idea to use recursion but this is ok for simple cases.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Node {
    Node(std::string name) : name{name} {}
    std::string name;
    std::vector<Node> nodes;
};

void print(Node const &node, std::string const &predicate) {
    std::cout << predicate << " " << node.name << '\n';
    int i = 1;
    for (auto const &n : node.nodes) {
        std::string new_predicate = "  " + predicate + std::to_string(i++) + ".";
        print(n, new_predicate);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Node tree{"Data types and expressions"};
    tree.nodes.emplace_back("Data types in C++");

    auto &p12 = tree.nodes.emplace_back("Constants");
    p12.nodes.emplace_back("What are Constants");
    p12.nodes.emplace_back("Mathematical constant");
    p12.nodes.emplace_back("Literal constant");

    auto &p13 = tree.nodes.emplace_back("Variables");
    p13.nodes.emplace_back("What are variables");
    p13.nodes.emplace_back("Variable naming rules");

    tree.nodes.emplace_back("Operators in C++");
    auto &p15 = tree.nodes.emplace_back("Arithmetic operators");
    p15.nodes.emplace_back("Basic rithmetic operators");

    print(tree, "1.");

    return 0;
}
```